# Thermal resistance calculation

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

[image]

With reference to the given diagram I am asked to find the thermal resistance of the interface(that is the common surface) between 1 and 2.All that I knew was the resistance diagram drawn right below.I do not understand why a third resistance should crop up.Secondly,the problem provides me the temperatures $T_L$,$T_R$,thermal conductivity of 1 and 2,the heat flux and the thickness of 1 and 2.I find that the question demands me to calculate the cross sectional area of 1 and 2.How do I get that?Does the area factor cancel out while solving for the interface thermal resistance?

Comment: The heat flux is equal to the heat flow divided by the area.

Comment: @Chet Miller Does the area cancel out by any chance? Why would the common surface generate a resistance?

Comment: If the two materials don't make perfect contact, there can be resistance at the common surface from air in the interstices.

Comment: Thermal contact resistance is the inverse of thermal contact conductance.  See the following link for a full explanation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_contact_conductance